# Missing a value from submitted HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've written the following code which records whether user submitted answers are correct. 
score_one is either 0 or 1 for getting the first question right, score_two is either 0 or 1 for getting the second question right and so on.
totalScore is basically the sum of score_one to score_four

What I would like is that the totalScore value returned through PHP to my email address. My current HTML form has an email field and a name field. I have a PHP script which is successfully sending these field answers to my inbox. However I can't get the totalScore value to appear. The code below is what I'm using but I'm not an expert

```
<input type="text" id="score" value="" disabled />
<script>

    var score_one = 0;
    var score_two = 0;
    var score_three = 0;
    var score_four = 0;
    var totalScore = 0;

    function fsubmit(){
        var correctFirstAnswer = document.getElementById("price_three");
        var correctSecondAnswer = document.getElementById("price_six");
        var correctThirdAnswer = document.getElementById("price_seven");
        var correctFourthAnswer = document.getElementById("price_eleven");

        if (correctFirstAnswer.checked === true){
            score_one = 1;
        }

        if (correctSecondAnswer.checked === true){
            score_two = 1;
        }

        if (correctThirdAnswer.checked === true){
            score_three = 1;
        }

        if (correctFourthAnswer.checked === true){
            score_four = 1;
        }

        totalScore = score_one + score_two + score_three +score_four;
    }


    document.getElementById("score").value = totalScore;
</script>
```

My PHP code snippet is:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];

$body = <<<EOD
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Score: $score <br>
```

A typical reply is:
Name: Mr Bloggs
Email: bloggs@bloggs.com
Score:

I get no value at all in the Score: part - no zero or anything.

Can anyone help? I would be really grateful - I'm not an expert coder, just muddling through really.

Comment: You're missing a closing `EOD` with a `;` on a new line after `Score: $score <br>`. And do think about escaping your input values.

Comment: Hi Fred, the closing EOD is on the next line - sry, I should have included that. How do I escape input values?

Comment: Have a look at this page on SO, there are many ways of doing this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

a disabled field will not be submitted [(RFC term: successful)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12).

*In this example, the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.
`<INPUT disabled name="fred" value="stone">`*

Answer (score 0):

Please simply modify this, by adding **name** attribute for an input:

```
<input type="text" id="score" value="" disabled />
```

==>

```
<input type="text" id="score" name="score" value="" disabled />
```

Only **named** input's can be posted, **id** attribute only inputs are not passed to your processing PHP script.